# Needed an example to understand the concept .

Tags: functional-analysis

I would be glad if anyone could provide me example of a Polar Set . 
Polar set is defined as follows: Given a dual pairing $(X,Y)$ the polar set or polar of a subset $A$ of $X$ is the set $A^0$ of $Y$ such that :

$$A^0 = \{y \in X : \sup |\langle x,y\rangle|\le1 \}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ be a subspace of a normed linear space $X$ with topological dual $X^\ast$. Then:
 $$E^0=\{f\in X^\ast:|f(x)|\leq 1,\,\forall x\in E\}=\{f\in X^\ast:f=0\text{ on } E\}$$
This is known as the [annihilator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Quotient_spaces_and_annihilators) of $E$ in $X^\ast$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $X=Y=R$. Let $A=[a,b]$. Then

$$A^0= \{ y \in \mathbb{R} :  |xy|\leq 1\quad \forall x \in A \}= [-c,c]  $$

where $c =\max \{ |a|, |b| \}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a normed space with norm-unit ball $B$ and continuous dual $X^*$. Then 
$$ B^\circ = \{ f \in X^*: |f(x)| \leq 1, \forall x \in B\} $$ is precisely the norm-unit ball $B^*$ in $X^*$. So the concept of a polar is the natural extension of norm-neighbourhoods of 0 to topological vector spaces.